# "Native platforms" decreased when uploading to Play Store and gave warning about "app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices"

Tags: android, google-play

When I uploaded the latest version of my native Android app to the Play Store, it gave me the following warning at first:

> Warning: Deactivation of this APK will result in your app being available for new installs on fewer types of devices

I decided to upload it anyway, as the number of supported devices was the same as before.

I thought this was a bit strange, as I didn't change my "minSdkVersion".
I released this version to only 1 % of the users, which is approximately 1500 users.

I actually don't know if I should be worried, but I have monitored the activity through AppCenter, which we have integrated into the app. And I think the number of users on the new version is suspiciously low. And 0 crashes in Play Store (which could be a good thing though).

Also, the column "Native platforms" in Play Store changed from 5 to 4.
At this moment I have the following in this column: "arm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a, x86, x86_64"

Unfortunately, I can't see the old information about this anymore, as I release another version afterward (a bug fix). But it was something like this I think:

> 1 differentiating: armeabi + 4 common: differarm64-v8a, armeabi-v7a,
>   x86, x86_64

Is this relevant to the number of users being able to download the app and should I be worried?

Comment: I have exactly same problem with me. Should I continue with with the release or any changes need to be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

don't worry about that.

> Note: Historically the NDK supported 32-bit and 64-bit MIPS, but support was removed in NDK r17.

https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis

"Native platforms" column changed because mips, mips64 removed in NDK r17.
Generally there isn't any MIPS mobile devices around.
don't forget to check "Supported Android devices".